# how can I insert organs into an empty array by the "for of" loop in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I created a class of user and created 3 users. now I want to insert all of the users I have created into an arrey by using the for of loop.
This is what I have done till now...

```
class User {
  name;
  email;
  address;
  isLogged; //methods login(isLogged) {
  if ((this.isLogged = true)) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is Online`);
  }
}
logout(isLogged) {
  if ((this.isLogged = false)) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is Offline`);
  }
}
getInfo() {
  console.log(`${this.name} (${this.email}) - Online `);
}
constructor(name, email, address, isLogged) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
  this.address = address;
  this.isLogged = isLogged;
  console.log("This user exists");
}
}
const user1 = new User("osh", "osh@jgh.com", "ashdod", true);
const user2 = new User("yan", "yan@jhh.com", "ashdod", false);
const user3 = new User("ella", "ealla@hjh.com", "rishon", true);
const users = [];
for (let user of users) {
  users.push(user[i]);
}
```

I know that I miss something but I dont Know what..
thanks for any help

Comment: הקלאס שלך לא כתוב נכון בשום צורה - תסתכלי על דוקומנטציה של קלאסים. בנוסף, הלולאה מתבצעת על מערך ריק. בשביל להכניס דברים למערך קיים תשתמשי בפוש, או שפשוט תצרי את המערך עם האלמנטים האלה.

Comment: `for of` loop is used iterate over the items of the array, your array doesn't have any items, so that loop doesn't run.

Comment: Ori Drori תודה על העריכה ועל התשובה

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can add users to the array:

```
const users = [];

users.push(new User("osh", "osh@jgh.com", "ashdod", true));
users.push(new User("yan", "yan@jhh.com", "ashdod", false));
users.push(new User("ella", "ealla@hjh.com", "rishon", true));
```

and only after this you can iterate array with for loop, to access those elements in array if you want:

```
for (let usr of users) {
    console.log(usr);
}
```